# How to name local workspace using command line interfaces while checking out files from CVS repository by means of a tag

Tags: jenkins, command-line, tags, cvs, vcs-checkout

Right now i am using below mentioned cvs command line argument for checking out files from CVS repository.

```
# Module1_1_20_2017 is the tag name.
#Test/user_Test/work is the module name.
cvs checkout -r Module1_1_20_2017 Test/user_Test/workload
```

I want contents of this `Test/user_Test/workload` module to be checked out into a local workspace folder named as `work` which is located at `C:\Jenkins\jobs\workspace\work`.

But every time when i use the above command it creates empty directories after this `C:\Jenkins\jobs\workspace\work` local workspace as `C:\Jenkins\jobs\workspace\work\Test\user_Test\workload`.
I want to get rid of these entire folders `Test\user_Test\workload` and after checking out files from  `Test/user_Test/work` this module the local workspace should look like `C:\Jenkins\jobs\workspace\work` (not `C:\Jenkins\jobs\workspace\work\Test\user_Test\workload`) and this local workspace `C:\Jenkins\jobs\workspace\work` should contain all the files of this `Test/user_Test/workload` module.

What cvs command line will satisfy this requirement?In short I want to create a local name as in jenkins job configuration shown in the picture attached below.
[image: In short I want to give a local name as shown in the picture attached below.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the form `cvs checkout -d <path> <module>`.
In your case that is `cvs checkout -d work Test/user_Test/workload`

(Did `cvs checkout --help` not give you this answer?)

Comment: I want to perform this with sticky tag

Comment: So, put the `-r <tag>` in the command. Surely you can figure that out.

Comment: cvs co -d work -r <tag_name> <module_name> this works for me.